# Why are my Bootstrap table rows 1px smaller than the table element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a html page to display a bill of materials in a bootstrap-table using sub tables.

Because a position can have a bom itself I want so display these kind of sub bom in a expandable sub table. Works fine except that the column's borders are offset.

I used the inspector tool to see whats wrong and the only thing I did identify was that the  are 1px smaller than the  element. And because I put a new table inside that  the offsets gets bigger with every sub table.

Can someone help me to understand why the table rows are smaller than the table? How can I fix this issue or is there any other workarround?

My code is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8q7vgm4/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mehrstufige Stückliste mit Tabelle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
  <style>
    tr[data-has-detail-view="false"]>td:first-child>a {
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    table.sub>thead {
      visibility: collapse;
    }
    
    .bootstrap-table .detail-view>td {
      padding: 0 !important;
      border: none !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>Mehrstufige Stückliste</h2>
    <table id="table"></table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let $table = $('#table');

    function buildTable($element, data) {
      $element.bootstrapTable({
        columns: [{
          title: 'Position',
          field: 'position'
        }, {
          title: 'Materialnummer',
          field: 'materialnummer'
        }, {
          title: 'Menge',
          field: 'menge'
        }, {
          title: 'Gewicht',
          field: 'gewicht'
        }],
        data: data,
        detailView: true,
        rowAttributes: function(row, index) {
          if (!Array.isArray(row['bom'])) return {
            'data-has-detail-view': 'false'
          };
        },
        detailFormatter: detailView
      })
    }

    function detailView(index, row) {
      var $detail = $('<table class="sub"></table>')
      buildTable($detail, row['bom'])
      return $detail
    }

    let demoData = [{
        "position": "1",
        "materialnummer": "123456",
        "menge": "10",
        "gewicht": "5kg",
        "bom": [{
            "position": "1.1",
            "materialnummer": "654321",
            "menge": "2",
            "gewicht": "1kg",
            "bom": [{
              "position": "1.1.1",
              "materialnummer": "987654",
              "menge": "1",
              "gewicht": "0.5kg"
            }]
          },
          {
            "position": "1.2",
            "materialnummer": "654322",
            "menge": "3",
            "gewicht": "1.5kg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": "2",
        "materialnummer": "654321",
        "menge": "10",
        "gewicht": "5kg"
      }
    ];

    $(function() {
      fetch('sl.json')
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Response not ok');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          buildTable($table, data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error while fetching JSON:', error);
          buildTable($table, demoData)
        });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried various things with browser's inspection tool, nothing helped. I could not identify the problem.

Comment: I can't tell from the given example, what exactly the issue is supposed to be. Please clarify.

Comment: The columns adapt their widths to their content [automatically](https://drafts.csswg.org/css3-tables-algorithms/Overview.src.htm). Having a `-` or `+` in a column is more content than having nothing there. So the latter column will be narrower. You need to either specify the width, or not create new tables for the rows you want to insert.