# CSS Layout and positioning issue

Tags: html, css

This is a sample chatbot I am designing and I want the chatbot to extend to the whole screen right now I have set the height of the chat to 440px; and if I change the height of the chat container to 100% or 90% the input box and the corresponding send button is going down(i have to scroll to see the input field box) I need it to always be fixed at the bottom

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ecedf6b9;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #D5ECFB;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.attachment-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#chat-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(241, 241, 245, 255);
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#chat {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 440px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
}

#input-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#input-message {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#send-button,
#attach-button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #d5ecfbf6;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 13px;
  position: absolute;
}

#send-button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#input-message:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>chatbot</title>
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="chat-container" style="display:block;position:relative; ">

      <ul id="chat"></ul>

      <div id="input-container" style="position: relative;padding-left:0; display:flex;align-items:center; margin-bottom:0;">
        <input type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Type your message..." style=" margin-right:40px;width:100%;">
        <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;">
        <button id="attach-button" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top:90%; transform: translateY(-50%); margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -18px;">
            <img src="../images/file.png" class="attachment-icon" alt="file attachment icon">
        </button>
        <button id="send-button" style=" right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-46%); margin-right: 0%; padding: 18px;  margin-top:-1.5px;position:absolute;">
            <img src="../images/msgsend.png" class="attachment-icon" alt="send query icon">
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

I need the chatbot to be responsive, it already is, but when I try to minimize it vertically, I have to scroll down to see the input field I need it to always be fixed at the bottom, and also the send button next to it. Can someone help me with that

Comment: So do you want to toggle between minimizing and maximizing? And what means "when I try to do it"; what did you try?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what do you exactly want to achieve? I've removed     border: 2px solid #ccc; and it looks fine , plus by saleable, do you mean you want it to be responsive, if yes, then it is fully responsive here on my screen.

Comment: Hi I have edited my post, I am using the interface of microsoft copilot as a reference, I want the chatbot to extend to the whole screen removing the existing borders

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state that you have a vague issue. Also, please punctuate your sentences so you're more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS instead:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%; /* Ensure full height */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ecedf6b9;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end; /*this*/
    height: 100%; /* Ensure full height */
}
button {
    background-color:#D5ECFB;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    /* border-radius: 5px; */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* height : 16px; 
    width : auto;  */
    
}


  
  .attachment-icon {
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
  }


  #chat-container {
    /* flex-grow: 1;  */
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 245, 255);
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Align content at the bottom */
}

#input-container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 245, 255);
}


#chat {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* height:440px; THIS */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling when content exceeds height */
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}



#input-message {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#send-button,
#attach-button {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #d5ecfbf6;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#input-message:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#send-button { 
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#input-message:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>chatbot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    

    <main>
        <section id="chat-container" style = "display:block;position:relative; ">
 
            <ul id="chat">
            </ul>
            
            <div id="input-container" style="position: relative;padding-left:0; display:flex;align-items:center; margin-bottom:0;">
                <input type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Type your message..." style=" margin-right:40px;width:100%;">
                <input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;">
                <button id="attach-button" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top:90%; transform: translateY(-50%); margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -18px;">
                    <img src="../images/file.png" class="attachment-icon" alt="file attachment icon">
                </button>
                <button id="send-button" style=" right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-46%); margin-right: 0%; padding: 18px;  margin-top:-1.5px;position:absolute;">
                    <img src="../images/msgsend.png" class="attachment-icon" alt="send query icon">
                </button>
            </div>   
            
        </section>
    </main>
  
    
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comments in this CSS are added for your understanding.Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Would you please explain what do you mean by "copy the snippet to your answer" ?

Comment: Have a look at this [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77977503/1264804). See the Copy Snippet to Answer button? That's how you demonstrate your solution. You can also manually create a demo using the editor. Have a closer look so you know what features it offers.